# Xamarin and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xamarin

We are just about to start developing an iOS and Android app with Xamarin.

The app will include a user log in and saving/getting data from our SQL Server database.

There seem to be some different approaches, which way is best to connect securely to our database through the app?

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to wrap your SQL calls in a web service then you can invoke them in your Xamarin application. Here is a guide http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/Application_Fundamentals/Web_Services/